# How to return value based on if condtion in function? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is my function which return price of Europe only

```
ALTER FUNCTION [prices].[UDF_Fn_IsPriceAvailable]
    (@Product NVARCHAR(100),
     @Region NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        (SELECT ISNULL(PRICE, 0) AS PRICE
         FROM [dbo].[tblPricesEurope]
         WHERE product = @Product

END
```

Now the problem is my function should return price based on region.

I have two tables

- [dbo].[tblPricesEurope]
- [dbo].[tblPricesAsia]

I am not very good at my SQL skills. I am not able to return the price based on the region?

What I have tried but I keep getting this error

> The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [prices].[UDF_Fn_IsPriceAvailable]
    (@Product NVARCHAR(100),
     @Region NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    IF (@Region = 'Europe')
    BEGIN 
        RETURN 
            (SELECT ISNULL(PRICE, 0) AS PRICE
             FROM [dbo].[tblPricesEurope]
             WHERE product = @Product)
    END
    ELSE IF (@Region = 'Asia') 
    BEGIN 
        RETURN 
            (SELECT ISNULL(India,0) AS PRICE
             FROM [dbo].[tblPricesAsia]
             WHERE product = @Product)
    END
END
```

Comment: Why you have two tables in the first place? Why not just one with Region column? Also why your function returns `NVARCHAR(100)` since you're selecting a price?

Comment: @Sami  both the tables column structure is diffrent and i want as a nvarchar becoz i just  print the value

Comment: Better is to let the function return the value in the correct type and let the caller of the function convert. This way your function will be much better re-usable

Comment: What **datatype** is your `PRICE` column??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error really says it all - there has to be **ONE** final `RETURN` statement - so change your code to:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [prices].[UDF_Fn_IsPriceAvailable]
    (@Product NVARCHAR(100),
     @Region NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS DECIMAL(20,2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result DECIMAL(20,2);

    IF (@Region = N'Europe')
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @Result = ISNULL(PRICE, 0.0) 
        FROM [dbo].[tblPricesEurope]
        WHERE product = @Product
    END
    ELSE IF (@Region = N'Asia') 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @Result = ISNULL(PRICE, 0.0) 
        FROM [dbo].[tblPricesAsia]
        WHERE product = @Product
    END

    RETURN @result;
END
```

Also: if you have a **numeric** `PRICE` column - ***why on earth*** does this function return a `NVARCHAR` result?!?!?!? I changed this to a more reasonable `DECIMAL(20,2)` return type.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
DECLARE @Result DECIMAL(20,2);

SELECT
  @Result = ISNULL(PRICE, 0.0)
FROM
(
  SELECT PRICE
  FROM [dbo].[tblPricesEurope]
  WHERE product = @Product AND @Region = N'Europe'

  UNION ALL  

  SELECT PRICE
  FROM [dbo].[tblPricesAsia]
  WHERE product = @Product AND @Region = N'Asia'
) AS X
```

Because of the constant in the where conditions, it will return only the results from the selected table.

With this you don't have to play with the IF statements, just make sure, that each table has it's own dedicated constant.

Comment: this solution will work, but it will execute 2 queries. So in matter of performance it might not be the best alternative

Comment: The constant comparison will rule out one of the sub-queries and will shorthand to 0 records due to impossible where condition. It is like querying using WHERE 1 = 2

Answer (score 0):

you want to return value based on if conditions in function in [SQL Server](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/search/label/SQL%20Server) then you can pass the `output parameter` in your stored procedure and that is a good approach.

I have made a simple demo for you for insert records in the user table and returning validation messages and appropriate other messages based on the condition.

To get detailed information for `output parameter` you can visit this [article](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-pass-output-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-microsoft-sql-server.html) where I explained all the information in detail so, you can get more idea about `output parameter`

**LINK** : https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-pass-output-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-microsoft-sql-server.html

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE L_UsersIns
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) ,  
    @LastName VARCHAR(50) ,  
    @Email VARCHAR(50) ,  
    @ReturnValue VARCHAR(50) = '' OUT  
AS   
    BEGIN  

        SET NOCOUNT ON ;  

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM L_Users WHERE UserName = @UserName) 
  BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = @UserName + ' is Already Exists, Please Try Different Username.'  
   RETURN
  END

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM L_Users WHERE Email = @Email) 
  BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = @Email + ' is Already Exists, Please Try Different Email.'  
   RETURN
  END

        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM L_Users  WHERE   UserName = @UserName AND Email = @Email)   
            BEGIN  
                INSERT  INTO L_Users  
                        ( 
                          FirstName ,  
                          LastName ,  
                          Email  
                        )  
                VALUES  ( 
                          @FirstName ,  
                          @LastName ,  
                          @Email   
                        )  
                SET @ReturnValue = @UserName + ' is Registered Successfully'  
            END  
        ELSE   
            BEGIN  
                --SET @ReturnValue = 1  
                SET @ReturnValue = @UserName + ' is Already Exists'  
            END  
    END
```